# Let Y be a Geometric Random Variable with parameter p, find EY

Tags: probability

Let Y be a Geometric Random Variable with parameter p, find EY

I think this is the right answer.

EY= $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}p$ =$p\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(1-p)^{n-1}$ = $p {1\over (1-(1-p))^2}$ = ${1\over p}$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method to compute $\mathbb E[Y]$:
\begin{align}
\mathbb E[Y] &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb P(Y\geqslant n)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-p)^{n-1}\\
&= \frac1p.
\end{align}